# Does anybody use Clamato?

Tags: javascript, smalltalk

I'm interested if anyone uses [clamato](http://clamato.net) in a production environment?

Comment: Yes! [In cocktails](http://www.clamato.com/en/) after a hard day of work.

Comment: looks like a really cool project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author ([Avi Bryant](http://twitter.com/avibryant)) used on [Trendly](http://trendly.com/) (which got [bought](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/twitter_acquires_smallthought_systems.php) recently by twitter, [along with the rest of the company](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/06/more-than-dabbling.html)). The official [repository](http://bitbucket.org/avibryant/clamato/src) hasn't changed in a few months though, but there is a [fork](https://bitbucket.org/abbat/clamato-abbat) that has seen changes in the last month.

Clamato recently got some of attention from Yehuda Katz [new blog post](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1692500), linking to Avi's [presentation](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1186/django-is-obsolete-but-so-is-e) on DjangoCon.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some of it went to form [Amber](http://amber-lang.net/), a Smalltalk for the Browser.

Answer (score 0):

No! And is obviously because nobody else has answered it in past 5+ months.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue with using anything that does not have a huge user base when using it in a production environment is how willing are you to roll up your sleeves and dig into the code and find problems.  Which leds to how does one go about debugging generated javascript? Perhaps a good place to look is to the cappuccino framework.